# Using instanceof in java 14 vs java 17

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

My code  runs in intellij on java 17 but returns an error on java 14 for the following line:

`if (this.areas.get(i) instanceof Habitat area) {`

which returns the error:

*java: pattern matching in instanceof is a preview feature and is disabled by default.*

How does one adjust this line so it works in java 14? I am aware the way I have used this feature only works in java 16+.

Answer (score 8):

You have two options.

(1) You can enable the preview feature in Java 14, by compiling with

```
javac MainClass.java --enable-preview --release 14
```

and running with

```
java MainClass --enable-preview
```

(2)  The line you wrote is equivalent to this.

```
if (this.areas.get(i) instanceof Habitat) {
    Habitat area = (Habitat) this.areas.get(i);

    // ... more here
```

Assuming, of course, that this `get` method doesn't have any nasty side-effects.  This is how you do it if you don't want to enable the preview feature.

Answer (score 4):

The old way is to test instanceof and them cast to the desired type:

```
if(this.areas.get(i) instanceof Habitat) {
  Habitat area = (Habitat) this.areas.get(i);
// rest of the if block
```